# How can I stop ng-bootstrap modal from automatically centering modal content?

Tags: css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I have an Angular ng-bootstrap modal that is used to display a message of an indeterminate length. My problem is that whenever a message is longer than the vertical resolution of the screen, the message is centered on the screen which is a UX problem for very long messages where the user has to scroll all the way back to the top of the message to read it.

I've tried setting the centered property of the modal explicitly to false and it doesn't change the behavior.  I suspect that there is a CSS solution to this, and I've used the modalDialogClass setting with a custom class but cannot seem to get anything to change.  I'm at a loss at how to approach this problem and would appreciate any help.

This is the Angular code where I call open on the modal:

`this.currentDialog = this.modalService.open(MessageDetailComponent, { backdrop: 'static', modalDialogClass: 'modalPositioning' });`

`this.currentDialog.componentInstance.msgDetail = this.message;`

I'm also thinking to call the CSS styles in-line like below but don't know where to begin with the actual CSS:

`@Component({`

`styles: ['modalPositioning { top: 0 }]`

`})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution after reading Bootstrap's documentation on modals.  ng-bootstrap provides an option called 'scrollable' that is set to false by default.  Setting it to true will set long content to the top of the screen instead of centering it in the screen.